# Cipher doFinal pad block corrupted while decrypting file with AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle

I am creating a program that lets users upload and download encrypted files and decrypt them if they have the correct permissions to do so. Encrypting and uploading is fine, and so is downloading, but when I try to decrypt I get the "pad block corrupted" error.

What I am trying to do is take the encrypted file and then make a copy that is unencrypted

I shortened what I could so please don't comment that it looks incomplete.

KeyGen:

```
public static SecretKey genGroupSecretKey() {
    try {
        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC");
        keyGen.init(128);
        return keyGen.generateKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Encrypt:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile)) {
    response = Utils.decryptEnv((byte[]) tempResponse.getObjContents().get(0), fsSecretKey, ivSpec);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);

    do {
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

        int n = fis.read(buf); // can throw an IOException
        else if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("Read error");
            fis.close();
            return false;
        }

        byte[] cipherBuf = cipher.doFinal(buf);

        // send through socket blah blah blah

    } while (fis.available() > 0);
```

Decrypt:

```
   ...     

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey, ivSpec);

    File file = new File("D_" + filename); // D_ for decrypted
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename)) {
        do {
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int n = fis.read(buf);
            if (n < 0) {
                System.out.println("Read error");
                fis.close();
                return false;
            }

            byte[] cipherBuf = cipher.doFinal(buf);  // ERROR HERE
            System.out.println("IS THIS WORKING WTF: " + new String(cipherBuf));
            fos.write(cipherBuf, 0, n);

        } while (fis.available() > 0);
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should you `Cipher.doFinal()` only for the very last block of data. You should modify both your encryption and decryption code to use `Cipher.update()` for all intermediate data and use a single call to `Cipher.doFinal()` at the end. It is permitted to use `Cipher.update()` for all intermediate data block and just call the `Cipher.doFinal()` with the empty array at the end.

Also, you are ignoring the return value of `fis.read(buf)` when you pass the data read from the stream to the cipher.

Also, you are using `InputStream.available()` as a condition to end the cycle. Even if the code inside the cycle would be correct, you would be getting unpredictable results due to spurious triggering of cycle condition.

Use the following pattern to work with the ciphers:

```
Cipher cipher = ...
InputStream in = ...
OutputStream out = ...

byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
int r = in.read(inputBuffer);
while ( r >= 0 ) {
    byte[] outputUpdate = cipher.update( inputBuffer, 0, r );
    out.write( outputUpdate );
    r = in.read(inputBuffer);
}
byte[] outputFinalUpdate = cipher.doFinal();
out.write( outputFinalUpdate );
```

Check other variants of `Cipher.update()` - it is possible to use two pre-allocated buffers and minimize additional allocations.

Also check if you can reuse `javax.crypto.CipherInputStream` and `javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream` classes so that you do not have to work with the cipher  directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Always good to see an answer that isn't a link. Right now I'm just testing with text files that are only 2 lines long though, definitely not enough to fill up my buffer. Any ideas?

Comment: It does not matter whether the buffer is filled or not. You must not ignore the return value of `InputStream.read(byte[])` and you must use it when you pass the data to the next class.

Comment: Ok I'll report back when I've made the changes.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying that the byte array: outputUpdate = null, not sure why this is happening

Comment: nevemind, it's because the block was too small. i'm testing with bigger docs now. how would you deal with a block that is too small though?

Comment: I got everything working, thanks again! accepted this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is just to encrypt and decrypt a file, the following program would help.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.ShortBufferException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.fiberlink.security.crypto.CryptoUtils;

public class DecryptDocsController {

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    public static final String PKCS7_PADDING = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    public static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 16;
    public static final int STARTING_LOCATION = 0;
    public static final int STREAM_FINISH_LOCATION = -1;
    public void encryptFile() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
        {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DECRYPTED_FILE_LOCATION_1);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ENC_FILE_LOCATION_1);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(PKCS7_PADDING);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getEcryptionByte(FILE_ENCRYPION_KEY), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        CipherInputStream inputStream = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int count =0;
        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        while((count=(inputStream.read(data, STARTING_LOCATION, CHUNK_SIZE))) != STREAM_FINISH_LOCATION) {
            fos.write(data, STARTING_LOCATION, count);
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
        inputStream.close();
       }

    public void decryptFile() throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException 
        {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ENC_FILE_LOCATION_2);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(DECRYPTED_FILE_LOCATION_2);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(PKCS7_PADDING);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getEcryptionByte(FILE_ENCRYPION_KEY), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        CipherInputStream inputStream = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int count =0;
        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        while((count=(inputStream.read(data, STARTING_LOCATION, CHUNK_SIZE))) != STREAM_FINISH_LOCATION) {
            fos.write(data, STARTING_LOCATION, count);`enter code here`
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
        inputStream.close();
        }
}
```